# How to get and set the default output directory in Robot Framework(Ride) in Run time

Tags: robotframework

I would like to move all my output files to a custom location, to a Run directory created based on Date time during Run time. The output folder by datetime is created in the TestSetup

I have function "Process_Output_files" which will move the files to the Run folder(Run1,Run2,Run3 Folders).

I have tried using the argument-d  and used the function "Process_Output_files" as suite tear down to move the output files to the respective Run directory.

But I get the following error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I know this is because the Robot Framework (Ride) is currently using this.

If I dont use the -d argument, the output files are getting saved in temp folders.

```
c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\temp\RIDEfmbr9x.d\output.xml
c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\temp\RIDEfmbr9x.d\log.html
c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\temp\RIDEfmbr9x.d\report.html
```

My question is, Is there a way to get move the files to custom location during run time with in Robot Framework.

Comment: FWIW, the robot frameework and RIDE are two different things. RIDE is just the IDE. The framework is separate, and doesn't need or use RIDE in order to run.

Comment: It's unclear why you aren't using the `-d` option. Why does that not work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand the end result you want is to have your output files in their custom folders.  If this is your desire, it can be accomplished at runtime and you won't have to move them as part of your post processing.  This will not work in RIDE, unfortunately, since the folder structure is created dynamically. I have two options for you.

### Option 1:  Use a script to kick off your tests

RIDE is awesome, but in my humble opinion, one shouldn't be using it to run ones tests, only to build and debug ones tests.  Scripts are far more powerful and flexible.

Assuming you have a test, test2.txt, you wish to run, the script you use to do this could be something like:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import os

#strftime returns string representations of a date-time tuple.
#gmtime returns the date-time tuple representing greenwich mean time 
dts=strftime("%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S", gmtime())


cmd="pybot -d Run%s test2"%(dts,)
os.system(cmd)
```

As an aside, if you do intend to do post processing of your files using rebot, be aware you may not need to create intermediate log and report files.  The output.xml files contain everything you need, so if you don't want to create superfluous files, use `--log NONE  --report NONE`

### Option 2:  Use a [listener](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg-history/2.0.3/doc/userguide/src/ExtendingRobotFramework/ListenerInterface.txt) to do post processing

A listener is a program you write that responds to events (x_start, x_end, etc).  The `close()` event is akin to the teardown function and is the last thing called.  So, assuming you have a function `moveFiles()` you simply need to create a listener class (myListener), define the `close()` method to call your `moveFiles()` function, and alert your test that it should report to a listener with the argument `--listener myListener`.

This option should be compatible with RIDE though I admit I have never tried to use listeners with the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Sisy, I figured out a way to do this in run time. Solution is: Create .py file which will create your run time report directory and pass it as an argument when you call the robot.run function.

Comment: If you're writing a python script you don't need to call `os.system`. Robot has an API for running tests from python. See https://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.8.4/autodoc/robot.html#robot.run.run

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following syntax in RIDE (Arguments:) to create the output in newfolders dynamically

```
--outputdir C:/AutomationLogs/%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% --timestampoutputs
```

The above syntax gives you the output in below folder:

```
Output:  C:\AutomationLogs\20151125\output-20151125-155017.xml
Log:     C:\AutomationLogs\20151125\log-20151125-155017.html
Report:  C:\AutomationLogs\20151125\report-20151125-155017.html
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Karthik VN, Where do i go in ride to write this Argument ? Not able to find it any where in Rhttp://stackoverflow.com/users/5602347/karthik-vnIDE ?

Comment: Hi Karthik VN, how to give the timestamp also added to the output folder name

Comment: I got it, its the below command , `--outputdir TestResult-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2% --timestamp` then  output will be in the below folder : `Output:  D:\RobotPoC\TestResult\20170209152358\output-20170209-152359.xml`

Comment: Hey @vinu,  There is a Run Tab in RIDE tool. The Argument Text box is within this Tab.

Comment: Hey @SaradaAkurathi , my strong guess, your automation will throw an error from 12am to 9:59am. That's because the %time% will return **single digit hour stamp** that cause syntax error during pybot execution. Syntax error due to single space in folder name, caused due to single digit hour stamp. I guess, i havent tried it yet.

Comment: Hi @karthik, but i got the time in **two digit hour stamp** like as 'RobotPoC-20170213-130354`

Comment: Yes. You have executed at time **13:03:54**. RobotPoC-**20170213-130354**.  And for the example you mentioned above, folder creation time was at **15:23:58**. D:\RobotPoC\TestResult **20170209152358**\output-20170209-152359‌​.xml.  Try to do some execution before 9.59 am.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can write a custom run script that handles the moving of files after the test case execution. In this case the files are no longer used by pybot.

Comment: Do you have a sample? If so please provide the example. I want the script to execute in every OS. So I am thinking about .py script.

Comment: @Karthick here you go, this is what i am using: 

`import os
import sys
testexecute = sys.argv[1]
#print testexecute
os.system("pybot -d ../rflog "+ testexecute)`