# How to change reports or output saving location in robot framework from RIDE

Tags: robotframework

When I run test cases from RIDE the reports are saved in the below path.

C:\Windows\Temp\RIDExf4xla.d

I want save reports in specific path. Can I do this from RIDE? Is there any setting to change the reports location?

Can anyone please suggest the way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: did u try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919279/how-to-get-and-set-the-default-output-directory-in-robot-frameworkride-in-run

Comment: Ya I know about the external script which can do that, but I am looking for any settings available on RIDE UI to change the reports path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `--outputdir` command within the [Robot Framework Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id602):

Here is what I use:

```
--outputdir C:/Robot/AutomationLogs/etc/etc --timestampoutputs
```

You use this one liner on the "Arguments" Field, right on the top of RIDE within the run tab.

From [Wamans comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919279/how-to-get-and-set-the-default-output-directory-in-robot-frameworkride-in-run) you can add formats to the end of the argument, to also change the dir name dynamically. See the 2nd answer within that SO question. This should be enough for you to get what you're asking for.

There is no way to set this within a UI.

Just set it by pasting that argument option within the "Arguments" Field at the top.

Comment: Hi Goralight, Waman, I am able to save the reports to specific directory by using argument as  '--outputdir C:/Robot/AutomationLogs/etc/etc --timestampoutputs' . This is what I was looking for. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @sanjaypujari - Anytime! :) If it helped, mark the question as accepted so that it can help others in the future! :) Also, check more on the Robot Framework Documentation, there are a LOT of very useful arguments which can help you do cool, little things!

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

use below code in command line

```
    C:\Tests\> robot -d C:\Test_results Test.robot
```