# Implementing listener in Robot Framework - data.resource.variables aquired are empty

Tags: python, listener, robotframework

I am writing a listener for my test suite in Robot Framework to move my output files to directory with unique ID embedded into it based on the tested device ID. I was actually inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307094/3557726) and decided to try it myself:

```
class OutputFilesListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.output = ""
        self.log = ""
        self.report = ""
        self.unique_id = ""

    def end_suite(self, data, result):
        # I would like to get data.resource.variables to read global variable I set in one of the test cases based on some output
        print(data.resource.variables) # called properly, prints []
        print(data.resource.keywords) # called properly, prints [<robot.running.model.UserKeyword object at 0x7f88157e7978>, <robot.running.model.UserKeyword object at 0x7f88157d80f0>, <robot.running.model.UserKeyword object at 0x7f88157d8160>] - makes sense


    def output_file(self, path):
        self.output = path

    def log_file(self, path):
        self.log = path

    def report_file(self, path):
        self.report = path

    def close(self):
        print("{} {} {}".format(self.output, self.log, self.report))
        if self.log and self.report and self.output:
            print("All are there!") # This is fine - so in general values are properly passed
```

So it seems, that variables passed in `data.resource.variables` to `end_suite(...)` method are... well, empty. I have only checked `data.resource.keywords` and it seems that there are few - so something is properly filled. Also, I have already checked if the variable I set is available suite-wise, and it was properly logged in different test case.

Is there anything wrong with my listener code or maybe I should look for a problem in other part of my application?

FYI, this is a line that should set global variable and it works properly:

```
Run Keyword If      ${validationResult} == True   Set Global Variable     ${uniqueBoardId}     ${deviceId[1]}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get access to global variable `${uniqueBoardId}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to get the value of the variable `${uniqueBoardid}`. You don't do that through the `.resource` attribute. That attribute is useless in this context. It refers to the `*** Variables ***` table of the suite.

You can get the value of a variable by running the `get_variable_value` method from the BuiltIn library.

For example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
...
class OutputFilesListener(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    ...
    def end_suite(self, data, result):
        uniqueBoardId = BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${uniqueBoardId}`)
        print("the board id is %s" % uniqueBoardId)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, I haven't thought about that even though I used that method in my test libraries, though listener is somehow "out of scope", but can't think of any reason why I haven't tried it...

Comment: Just a small remark to your code, it seems that the `close()` method is out of get_variable_value scope, just like I subconsciously expected: `Calling method 'close' of listener 'listeners.OutputFilesListener.OutputFilesListener' failed: RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context`. But you can move `BuiltIn().get_variable_value` to `end_suite` method and then it works fine.

Comment: @olhur: yeah, I think that's a bug in robot. However, you didn't ask about accessing variables during `close`, your code asked about `endf_suite`.